# Libgdx: Why does my sprite not animate?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm building a small game using libGDX and currently trying to get something animated on the screen. Currently it only shows the first frame of the animation.

I'm using a thread to update and render (and this is where I suspect the issue is)

```
public class SuperBoopers extends Game implements ApplicationListener {
public static final int V_WIDTH = 480;
public static final int V_HEIGHT = 600;
public SpriteBatch batch;
FieldScreen screen;

private PauseableThread thread;
private boolean running = false;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    screen = new FieldScreen(this);
    setScreen(screen);
    running = true;
    thread = new PauseableThread(new Runnable() {
        long timeLast = System.nanoTime();
        final double ticks = 60D;
        double ns = 1000000000 / ticks;
        float dt = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running){
                long timeNow = System.nanoTime();
                dt += (timeNow - timeLast)/ns;
                timeLast = timeNow;

                if(dt >= 1) {
                    update();
                    render(dt);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void update(){
    screen.update();
}

public void render (float dt) {
    screen.render(dt);
}
```

and this is the class for the object being animated

```
public class Actor {
private static Texture atlas = new Texture("Atlas.png");

private Sprite sprite;
private int frames; //number of total frames for the animation
private int frameNumber; //current frame number
private int xi; //x location of the first frame in the texture atlas
private int yi; //y location of the first frame in the texture atlas
private int frameSize; //standard size of a single square frame in pixels


public Actor(int frames, int xi, int yi){
    this.frames = frames;
    this.xi = xi;
    this.yi = yi;
    frameNumber = 0;
    frameSize = 64;
    sprite = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(atlas, xi, yi, frameSize, frameSize));
}

public void update(){
    //checks what frame it's on, if was last frame, resets frame number
    if(frameNumber == frames-1){
        frameNumber = 0;
    } else {frameNumber++;}

    //scoots the TextureRegion forward the distance of one frameSize
    sprite.setRegionX(xi+(frameSize*frameNumber));
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
    sprite.draw(batch);
}}
```

I know I'm probably missing something really big and obvious here.

Comment: Can't tell without seeing your code in Screen. If you want to animate something, delta time needs to be a part of your formula, or you have no control over the speed. Also, you are reinventing the wheel here. Use TexturePacker, TextureAtlas, and the Animation class all included with LibGDX to save yourself a lot of work.

Comment: First of all, there is no need to create separate thread to call render to update the screen, this is done automatically by the framework (You extended Game class of libgdx), Secondly all the logic is present in Screen class which you have not shown here. Without your screen class, it is very difficult to figure out what is the problem with your code.

Comment: No need of extra threads, as @ParasMittal said. Check out on some example how drawing is done. I.e. there is that bucket game example: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game